# rails devise password protected resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to Rails so hope for your understanding. 
I have a following problem: I need to create a password protected resource and I'm trying to figure out the best strategy for it using Devise. I would like my resource ( sort of a list ) to be available to certain people that have a password to it so basically there's no need for them to create user account etc.. I've read the devise documentation and it appears that I would have to use token authentication which would be a sort of API key. The problem is that I can't find any good example of such implementation. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You could use http basic. http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?autoplay=true

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want user accounts, you better off using http basic authentication.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

if you insist on devise API tokens you will need a user model that stores the auth token.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. User will need to be able to modify resource ( ajax calls ) so I will have to somehow attach this token to every request. Do you know of any way how to do that?